# how to write a logs of unhandled exception of flex air app with stacktrace?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flex4.5

I want to write log of unhandled exception of flex air app with stacktrace. Please let me know if there is any way to write stack trace of unhanded exception in error log file.

Comment: Go through this article for Global Error handling and writing LOG for Uncaught Exceptions     http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/global-exception-handling.html

Comment: It is only giving stack trace at the time of running app by flash builder, if I am making exe from flash builder and than applying this method than again it given null to the stacktrace.